# AJAX REST call don't send data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

After I click submit button, my form and page refreshes, and nothing is sent to datebase.

Code in subforum.js

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(e) {
var user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ulogovan"));
console.log("usao u submit");
alert("Usao");
var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
    'title': $('#titleSubforum').val(),
    'description': $('#descriptionSubforum').val(),
    'iconPath': $('#pictureSubforum').val(),
    'mainModerator': user.username,
    'rules': $('#rulesSubforum').val()

});

alert($('#rulesSubforum').val());

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : "../WebProjekat/rest/subforums/create",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : "json",
    data: dataObject,

    success : function(data) {
        console.log("USAO U CUVANJE ");
        alert("all good");
        window.location.href = "index.html";


    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("something wrong");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(user);

    }
});
});
```

code in SubforumController.java

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import beans.Subforum;
import services.SubforumService;

@Path("/subforums")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SubforumController {

private SubforumService subforumService = new SubforumService();

@GET
public List<Subforum> getSubforums() {
    return subforumService.getAllSubforums();
}

@POST
@Path("/create")
public Subforum createSubforum(Subforum subforum) {
    System.out.print(subforum.getTitle());

    return subforumService.createSubforum(subforum);
}
```

And code in SubforumService.java

```
package services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import datebase.DatebasePath;
import beans.Subforum;


public class SubforumService {

public SubforumService() {      
}

private Map<String, Subforum> subforums = DatebasePath.getSubforums();

public Subforum createSubforum(Subforum subforum) {
    subforums.put(subforum.getTitle(), subforum);
    DatebasePath.saveData(DatebasePath.subforumsPath);

    return subforum;
}

public List<Subforum> getAllSubforums() {
    return new ArrayList<Subforum>(subforums.values());
}

}
```

DatebasePath is good, becouse I hardcoded subforum object, and writed down to .txt file. I think that problem is between subforum.js and SubforumController.java

Comment: Check the console to see the error and/or response text from the requesrt

Comment: Did you forget to `e.preventDefault` of the submit button?  You've not included the html, so can't tell, but I'm assuming your submit button is `<input type='submit' id='submit'>submit</input>` - if so, change it to `<input type='button' id='submit'>submit</input>`

Comment: look at chrome inspector's network tab. does your server give http 404 or 200 or even nothing happen?

Comment: You're not calling your server, you're calling a local URL `"../WebProjekat/rest/subforums/create"`. No wonder this doesn't work.

Comment: @JeremyThille that's a relative path, relative to the page's url, so would use the same "server" that the page was rendered from (be it remote or local is unclear), it's not a "local URL".

Comment: Ah, that looks very weird to me, but I'm probably too used to Express routing.

Comment: Yes, I changed my submit button in html..  now in mozilla console i got 404, not found "../WebProjekat/rest/subforums/create", and I got alert "something wrong".

Comment: Looks like your relative path is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I click submit button, my form and page refreshes

this is frequently caused by the `form` post ocuring rather than your custom `$.ajax POST` code.

> and nothing is sent to database.

As `$.ajax POST` occurs asynchronously, the form's post occurs first, refreshing your page and thus not hitting your own submit handler.

There are two relatively easy options for this:

- `e.preventDefault` in the handler

eg

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // remaining code
```

- don't submit on the button

Change

```
<input type='submit' id='submit'>submit</input>
```

to

```
<input type='button' id='submit'>submit</input>
```